# Haskell split list determined by sum value

Tags: list, haskell

Hi all I am just a starter on Haskell. I have this list `[1.0, 2.0, 1.5, 1.5, n-1]`. How would I split this list to sub-list for example `[3.0, 3.0,etc]`. That is when added the values of the list, when the sum equals the given number(in this case 3), separates the list. I hope this question makes sense. Could someone point me out if there is a function in `Data.List` which can do this? or even the `filter` function. The only thing I have so far is:

```
import Data.List 

import Text.Printf


--separate :: [Double] -> [(Double)]

separate = sum [1.0, 2.0, 0.5, 2.5, 3.0, 1.1, 2.0] -- [(1.0, 2.0),(0.5, 2.5),(3.0),(1.1,2.0)] (desired list)



main = do
 putStrLn (printf "list :  %s" $ show separate)
```

---

More precisely, the requirements are:

```
separate :: Double -> [Double] -> [[Double]]
```

where `separate t xs = ys` implies

1. `concat ys = xs`
2. `all (near t . sum) ys`, where `near t x` is a predicate stating that `x` is "close" to `t` (semi-formal requirement).

Comment: It is not clear what the sub-lists should be. Could you provide more examples?

Comment: maybe sublist was wrong word to use.. i just want to split the big list to separate list where the values are around 3 . So from this [1.0, 2.0, 0.5, 2.5, 3.0, 1.1, 2.0] to [(1.0, 2.0),(0.5, 2.5),(3.0),(1.1,2.0)]

Comment: To recap, your requirements are: `separate :: Double -> [Double] -> [[Double]]` such that `separate t xs = ys` implies `concat ys = xs` and (less formally) `all (near t . sum) ys` where `near t x` is a predicate stating that `x` is "close" to `t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a recursive function can be written as

```
split :: [Double] -> [[Double]]
split x = go x [] 0
     where go [] _ _ = []
           go (x:xs) acc s | x+s>=3 = (acc++[x]) : go xs [] 0
                           | otherwise = go xs (acc++[x]) (s+x) 

split [1.0,2.0,0.5,2.5,3.0,1.1,2.0]
[[1.0,2.0],[0.5,2.5],[3.0],[1.1,2.0]]
```

carry an accumulator and sum so far, decide to carry forward or split based on the sum.

Note that, this is constructing "at least", not "near". So all sublists will be greater or equal to 3.0.